# How to add CSS dynamically to a controller in SAPUI5

Tags: html, css, sapui5, sap-fiori

I need to set height of a vertical layout dynamically. My page has a header image of height 100px, a tab of height 26px remaining part is the main content. I have written the following code in `App.controller.js`. It doesn't works

`// tab_layt is the id of vertical layout
var thisView = this.getView().byId("tab_layt");
var height = jQuery(window).height() - (jQuery(".header").height() + jQuery(".tab").height());
thisView.setHeight(height);`

it shows the error

> "thisView.setHeight is not a function".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sap.ui.layout.VerticalLayout` has no property called [height](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.layout.VerticalLayout.html).

Layout height will be aligned to the child elements' height automatically.
However, you can overwrite this by using custom CSS classes, but it's not really recommended.

```
thisView.addStyleClass("nameOfTheCssClass");
```

Or you can resize the child elements to fill the whole screen - this will resize the layout itself. For example, if you are using a table, you can set the height property of the table instead of the outer layout.

(variable name `thisView` is not the best if you are referencing to a layout, later it can cause misunderstanding when you are trying to understand your own code)

Comment: Thanks !!  I will make sure to use proper naming conventions. I thought of making a scrollable layout because it has lengthy form & it doesn't fit in the screen. Also it does not have so much data to have pagination.  Any other solution to make layout scrollable?

Comment: It depends on the data what you want to visualize. Lists, tables are contain scroll bars. Page object also contains a scrollbar if the elements in the `<content>` aggregation needs more space.

Comment: I have missed  <page>  <content>  tags within <pages> tag and so the scrollbar was hidden. Now that as you said, I have added those tags & the scrollbar is visible depending on the data. Thanks for your advise !!